# How to execute a function inside system function in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a text file named `meta.txt` with the following information:

[image]

And a folder named `data`

```
output_folder = "data"
```

Want to execute a function named `conv` inside the `system` function like below, which looks for `fastq.gz` using the path in the `2nd column` of `meta.txt` and converts the `fastq.gz` file into `fastq.txt`

```
tail -n+2 meta.txt | awk -v output_folder=${output_folder} '{ system("convert " $2 $output_folder/"fastq.txt") }'
```

But I ended up with the following error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

Comment: `awk` only uses `$` chars for variables to indicate the field number ($4, $i, etc). Using `.... $2 output_folder"/fastq.txt"` will get you closer. I can't be certain if you have the rest of the `convert` syntax correct.  Use`print $2 output_folder"/fastq.txt"` to see what you command is looking like. Good luck.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the example text here and use [code block]s for formatting.

Comment: Does your real `meta.txt` REALLY just have 2 lines in it? If not, please post some realistic multi-line sample input. If it does have more lines, do you REALLY want to have the same output file for every input file (so `foo.gz` is written to `fastq.txt` but then `bar.gz` also is written to `fastq.txt`) or do you actually want to dynamically create an output file name from every input file name (so `foo.gz` is written to `foo_fastq.txt` and then `bar.gz` is written to `bar_fastq.txt` or howvere you want the output files named)? Please add the expected output file names for the input you provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk is a tool to manipulate text, not a tool to sequence calls to other tools - that's what a shell is for. You didn't provide textual input/output to test with so this is an untested guess but I think all you need to do what your code is apparently trying to do is this shell loop (assumes `IFS` is unset or unmodified):

```
while read -r _ file; do
    convert "$file" "$output_folder/fastq.txt"
done < <(tail -n +2 meta.txt)
```

If you DID want to involve awk to call `convert` for some reason then it'd be:

```
output_folder="$output_folder" \
awk '
    BEGIN { outfold = ENVIRON["output_folder"] }
    NR>1{ system("convert \047" $2 ("\047 \047" outfold "/fastq.txt\047") }
' meta.txt
```

but that'd spawn a subshell every time system() was called so it'd be too slow for using awk to be of any benefit.

See [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) for more info on how I'm using `ENVIRON[]` or alternatives if your awk variant doesn't support `ENVIRON[]`.

As for why you're getting a divide by zero error - your code inside `system()` is:

```
"convert " $2 $output_folder/"fastq.txt"
```

where `output_folder` presumably contains some non-numeric string so if you ran `gawk --lint` you'd get a warning message like:

```
warning: attempt to field reference from non-numeric value
```

about that, but then you have `/` which is the division operator followed by the literal string `"fastq.txt"` which if it's treated as a number (as in this case) is equivalent to zero, hence "divide by zero".

**Regarding your comments and updated question:**

Change that function in your question:

```
function convert {
    INPUT=$1
    OUTPUT=$2

    INPUT_R=0
    if [ "${INPUT: -3}" == ".gz" ]; then
        INPUT_S=1
    fi
    if [[ $INPUT_R -eq 1 ]]; then
        gunzip -c ${INPUT} > ${OUTPUT}
    else
        cp -v ${INPUT} ${OUTPUT}
    fi
    chmod ug+rw ${OUTPUT}
}
```

to fix it's issues (some of which http://shellcheck.net would have told you about - always run that on your scripts until you get more familiar with shell):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

convert() {
    local input=$1 output=$2

    if [[ $input = *.gz ]]; then
        gunzip -c -- "$input" > "$output"
    else
        cp -v -- "$input" "$output"
    fi &&
      chmod -- ug+rw "$output"
}

output_folder='/Users/doc'

# now include this:
while read -r _ file; do
    convert "$file" "$output_folder/fastq.txt"
done < <(tail -n +2 meta.txt)

# or this at the end of the same script:
export -f convert # only works if sh is bash in your env since
                  # system() will call sh to run the command
output_folder="$output_folder" \
awk '
    BEGIN { outfold = ENVIRON["output_folder"] }
    NR>1{ system("convert \047" $2 ("\047 \047" outfold "/fastq.txt\047") }
' meta.txt
```

Note that you need to export your function if you want awk to be able to call it in a subshell. You'll have to figure out for yourself why the output file you're trying to use isn't writable by you but that should be easy.

As [StéphaneChazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) noted in comments (and thanks for additional comments now implemented above):

- If file paths can't be guaranteed not to contain `'` characters, that amounts to an arbitrary command injection vulnerability.
- That `\47` assumes an ASCII-based system (a relatively safe assumption these days).
- `chmod ug+rw` can be avoided by changing the `umask` to 0 (but in any case, making world writeable files sounds like a very bad idea).

Comment: I tried using this way `awk -v output_folder="$output_folder" 'NR>1{ system("convert " $2 " " output_folder "/fastq.txt") }' meta.txt` but it says `sh: line 1: convert: command not found`

Comment: I also posted the function `convert` in the question !!

Comment: And when I use this way `awk -v output_folder="$output_folder" 'NR>1 '{ system(convert  $2 " " output_folder "/fastq.txt") }' meta.txt` it gives the following error: `sh: line 1: /Users/doc/fastq.gz: Permission denied`

Comment: The first problem is that you haven't exported your `convert` function, the second is that you don't have permission to write to the file `/User/doc/fastq.gz`. I updated my answer to fix your function and show how to call it but you should get a single explicit call of `convert 'some_input_file' '/Users/doc/fastq.gz'` working first before worrying about adding a loop to call it on the contents of `meta.txt`. That "Permission denied" error has nothing to do with the loop or calling from awk.

Comment: Thank you. The only thing I'm missing is `export -f convert`. When I use it all went fine.

Comment: You're welcome. Just to be clear - you don't need that if you don't put `awk` in the middle of things and just call `convert` from a shell loop.

Comment: Sure thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

> fatal: division by zero attempted

Yeah, you've got quoting issues, so the `/` slash isn't
participating in a string operation the way you were hoping for.

---

Here is a very general strategy for debugging `awk` pipelines,
including quoting nonsense.

Instead of creating a string `cmd` and then executing `system(cmd)`,
hoping for the best, adopt another approach.
Ask your awk script to **output** that command string
to stdout, and then the last part of your pipeline is `sh` (or `bash`).

This has the advantages of

1. You can first view the proposed commands coming from `awk`, and *then* tack on `| sh` or `| sh -x` once things look good, and
2. During debugging of potentially harmful commands like `rm`, you first *see* what would happen before you *run* those commands.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need:

```
(
  umask 0
  unset -v IFS
  read -r discarded_header &&
    IFS=' ' read -r discarded_first_field file &&
    gzip -dcf < "$file" > data/fasq.txt
) < meta.txt
```

If the point is to make a world-readable and world-writable copy (possibly uncompressed) of the file whose path is in the second (and following) SPC/TAB delimited field of the second line of `meta.txt`.